# JTextArea.print() prints a blank page

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have the following `JTextArea`

```
reportText = new JTextArea();
reportText.setColumns(100);
reportText.setLineWrap(true);
reportText.setName("Output Report");
reportText.setAutoscrolls(true);
reportText.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12));
reportText.setEditable(false);
reportText.setSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
```

I'm simply looking to print the text in `reportText` as is via `reportView.getReportTextArea().print();`. However, the printer ends up printing a blank page. I've seen the [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380182/708969), but I am setting the size so I don't think that's my issue.

Note, that I'm setting text later on in the application, which I'm not showing here.

Is there anything else that I'm missing? Am I misunderstanding the `JTextComponent.print()` method?

Comment: And what did you see in screen? cause you are not appending any text

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to print the string `"Output Report"`, but then you must set it as the `JTextArea`'s text and NOT the name.

Try this to see that it works when the text is set.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrinterException {
        JTextArea reportText = new JTextArea();
        reportText.setText("Output Report");
        reportText.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the text is set elsewhere in the application.

Comment: @Neeko I guess it is not set, because if I only execute the code I provided (e.g. in a main method) it works. But here are some things you should check: Are you sure that the text is set? Are you sure that noone sets the foreground and background color to white?

Comment: No, the text is set elsewhere in the application  - I'm vote to close your question (sure isn't there an option - Shot into Dark)

Comment: Yes, close this question. I didn't make a single change to the code, but now it's printing properly, so there's no issue.

Comment: @Neeko But first you should set a breakpoint right before the `textArea.print()` statement and take a look at the variables of the `textArea`. Especially `model` which holds the `Document`.